# Finding piecewise function of $f(x) = \big||x − 1| − 1\big|$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I am having some difficulty with this problem where I need to put it into a piecewise function, $f(x) = \big||x − 1| − 1\big|$

I separated it into $x-1, -x+1, x-1-1, -x+1+1$

But the answer on the sheet for the piece wise looks like this:

$$−x , x ≤ 0;\quad
x , 0 < x ≤ 1;\quad
2 − x , 1 < x ≤ 2;\quad
x − 2 , x > 2$$

I don't know how we got $0$ for the function because I thought solving for $x$ would be $x = 1$, not $0$. Can someone help me out solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "we got $0$
 for the function" and by "solving for $x$"? And how did you "separate it into $x-1, -x+1, x-1-1, -x+1+1$? (and for which interval for $x$ for each of these 4 expressions?

Comment: Recall that $|x|$ is$$\begin{cases}-x,&x\le0\\x,&x>0.\end{cases}$$ Therefore, $\big\lvert\lvert x-1\rvert-1\big\rvert$ equals $$\begin{cases}-\big(\lvert x-1\rvert-1\big),&\lvert x-1\rvert-1\le0\\\lvert x-1\rvert-1,&\lvert x-1\rvert-1>0.\end{cases}$$Can you see how to continue? EDIT: Anne Bauval's approach may be simpler.

Comment: Or more simply, from "inside": $$f(x)=\begin{cases}|(x-1)-1|,&x\ge1\\|(1-x)-1|,&x\le1.\end{cases}$$ Anyway, please read [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) and [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I don't think the answer sheet is right either.  $f(2) = 0$ for instance.

Comment: It might be simpler to start looking at $x \mapsto ||x|-1|$.

Answer (score 2):

We may write $f(x)$ as $f(x)=g(g(x))$ where $g(x)=|x-1|$. Some observations: If $x\geq1$, $g(x)=x-1$, and if $x<1$, $g(x)=1-x$. Therefore:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x-1 & x\geq 1 \\ 1-x & x<1\end{cases}$$
Similarly
$$f(x)=g(g(x))=\begin{cases}g(x)-1 & g(x)\geq 1 \\ 1-g(x) & g(x)<1\end{cases}$$
Some other observations: note $g(x)\geq 1$ when $x\geq 2$ or when $x\leq 0$. Therefore
$$||x-1|-1|=f(x)=g(g(x))=\begin{cases}|x-1|-1 & x\geq 2~\text{or}~x\leq 0 \\ 1-|x-1| & x\in(0,2)\end{cases}$$
We break up the absolute values further:
$$||x-1|-1|=\begin{cases}(x-1)-1 & x\geq 2 \\ (1-x)-1 & x\leq 0 \\ 1-(1-x) & x\in (0,1) \\ 1-(x-1) & x\in[1,2) \end{cases}$$

Simplifying:
$$\boxed{||x-1|-1|=\begin{cases}x-2 & x\geq 2 \\ -x & x\leq 0 \\ x & x\in (0,1) \\ 2-x & x\in [1,2)\end{cases}}$$